# How can this repeated code be condensed into a function?

Tags: c++

I am making a game of console pong as a new programmer and do not know how I can condense my very repetitive code into a function.

I have attempted to make this chunk of code into a function, but I cannot figure out what the code would return.

```
case 1:
            currentX--;
            delay = 75;
            direction = BumperBounce(currentX, currentY, char1PosTop, char1PosMid, char1PosMidBot, char1PosBot, char2PosTop, char2PosMid, char2PosMidBot, char2PosBot, direction);
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if ((matrix[i][0] == 'O') || (matrix[0][0] == 'O') || (matrix[12][0] == 'O')) {
                    matrix[currentY][currentX] = ' ';
                    currentX = 14;
                    currentY = 6;
                    char2Points++;
                    direction = (rand() % 8);
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if ((matrix[i][28] == 'O') || (matrix[0][28] == 'O') || (matrix[12][28] == 'O')) {
                    matrix[currentY][currentX] = ' ';
                    currentX = 14;
                    currentY = 6;
                    char1Points++;
                    direction = (rand() % 8);
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
                }
            }
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(delay));
            if (direction == oldDirection) {
                currentX--;
                currentY++;
            }
            break;
```

So I have four cases which use these two for loops. What these for loops do is determine if the 'ball' is on the far right or far left side of the screen. If it is, it will raise the appropriate players points by 1. Now I would like to put these two for loops into one or two functions, but I don't know what I would put in the return. I don't know how this function would globally raise the appropriate players points by one.

Comment: If you pass `matrix` and a reference to `char1Points` (or `char2Points`, or a vector containing both) as parameters to your new function, there is no need for a return at all and the function can simply be type `void`. (you would also need to pass a reference to `direction`)

Comment: Why do you want to give this function a return value? What purpose does it serve? (Why not a `void` function?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organize your game parameters into a struct ( to avoid declaring them as global) like so:

```
struct para_t {
    int currentX, currentY, char1PosTop, char1PosMid, char1PosMidBot, char1PosBot, char2PosTop, char2PosMid, char2PosMidBot, char2PosBot, char1Points, char2Points, direction;
};
```

Then the declaration of `BumperBounce` will look similar to this:

```
int BumperBounce(struct para_t para);
```

Now your function prototype will look like so:

```
void process(int matrix[100][100], struct para_t& para, int oldDirection);
```

You can now call it like so:

```
 /* your code*/
 case 1:
    process( matrix, para, oldDirection);
    break;    
/* more code*/
```

The `process` definition can be condensed like so:

```
void process(int matrix[100][100], struct para_t& para, int oldDirection) {
    para.currentX--;
    int delay = 75;
    para.direction = BumperBounce(para);

    for (int loop = 0; loop < 2; loop++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if ((matrix[i][loop == 0 ? 0 : 28] == 'O') || (matrix[0][loop == 0 ? 0 : 28] == 'O') || (matrix[12][loop == 0 ? 0 : 28] == 'O')) {
                matrix[para.currentY][para.currentX] = ' ';
                para.currentX = 14;
                para.currentY = 6;
                para.char2Points++;
                para.direction = (rand() % 8);
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

            }
        }
    }

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(delay));

    if (para.direction == oldDirection) {
        para.currentX--;
        para.currentY++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

not all function have to return something?
I would consider using a void function with 1 parameter.
something like:

Assuming char1Points and char2Points are integer and I did not compile this code it is just written as a helpful tip

```
void foo(int charpoint){
    matrix[currentY][currentX] = ' ';
    currentX = 14;
    currentY = 6;
    charpoint++;
    direction = (rand() % 8);
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
}
```